# Proving a probability equation

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Prove that $$P[\overline D ∩F] = P[F]−P[D ∩F].$$ It is known that  $$F = (D∩F)∪(\overline D∩F)  $$

So I tried to prove it but I am stuck at $$ P[(D ∩F) ∪ (D ∩F)] - P[(D ∩ (D ∩F) ∪ (\overline D ∩F)  $$
Am I on the right track so far?

Answer (score 4):

Hint:$$F = (D\cap F)\cup(\overline D \cap F)  $$

$$\emptyset = (D\cap F)\cap(\overline D \cap F)  $$

$$P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$P(F)=P(F\cap D)+P(F\cap D^c)$$

which can be shown as follows:

$$\begin{align*}
P(F) 
&=P(F∩(D∪D^c))\\\\
&=P((F∩D)∪(F∩D^c))\\\\
&=P(F∩D)+P(F∩D^c)
\end{align*}$$

Comment: How did you get P(F) though?